# Constructing a JSON object from a bash associative array

Tags: json, bash, jq

I would like to convert an associative array in bash to a JSON hash/dict. I would prefer to use JQ to do this as it is already a dependency and I can rely on it to produce well formed json. Could someone demonstrate how to achieve this?

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A dict=()

dict["foo"]=1
dict["bar"]=2
dict["baz"]=3

for i in "${!dict[@]}"
do
    echo "key  : $i"
    echo "value: ${dict[$i]}"
done

echo 'desired output using jq: { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3 }'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are many possibilities, but given that you already have written a bash `for` loop, you might like to begin with this variation of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Requires bash with associative arrays
declare -A dict

dict["foo"]=1
dict["bar"]=2
dict["baz"]=3

for i in "${!dict[@]}"
do
    echo "$i" 
    echo "${dict[$i]}"
done |
jq -n -R 'reduce inputs as $i ({}; . + { ($i): (input|(tonumber? // .)) })'
```

The result reflects the ordering of keys produced by the bash `for` loop:

```
{
  "bar": 2,
  "baz": 3,
  "foo": 1
}
```

In general, the approach based on feeding jq the key-value pairs, with one key on a line followed by the corresponding value on the next line, has much to recommend it. A generic solution following this general scheme, but using NUL as the "line-end" character, is given below.

#### Keys and Values as JSON Entities

To make the above more generic, it would be better to present the keys and values as JSON entities.  In the present case, we could write:

```
for i in "${!dict[@]}"
do
    echo "\"$i\""
    echo "${dict[$i]}"
done | 
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $i ({}; . + { ($i): input })'
```

#### Other Variations

JSON keys must be JSON strings, so it may take some work to ensure that the desired mapping from bash keys to JSON keys is implemented. Similar remarks apply to the mapping from bash array values to JSON values.  One way to handle arbitrary bash keys would be to let jq do the conversion:

```
printf "%s" "$i" | jq -Rs .
```

You could of course do the same thing with the bash array values, and let jq check whether the value can be converted to a number or to some other JSON type as desired (e.g. using `fromjson? // .`).

#### A Generic Solution

Here is a generic solution along the lines mentioned in the jq FAQ and advocated by @CharlesDuffy. It uses NUL as the delimiter when passing the bash keys and values to jq, and has the advantage of only requiring one call to jq.  If desired, the filter `fromjson? // .` can be omitted or replaced by another one.

```
declare -A dict=( [$'foo\naha']=$'a\nb' [bar]=2 [baz]=$'{"x":0}' )

for key in "${!dict[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\0%s\0' "$key" "${dict[$key]}"
done |
jq -Rs '
  split("\u0000")
  | . as $a
  | reduce range(0; length/2) as $i 
      ({}; . + {($a[2*$i]): ($a[2*$i + 1]|fromjson? // .)})'
```

Output:

```
{
  "foo\naha": "a\nb",
  "bar": 2,
  "baz": {
    "x": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I like that this only invokes jq once with newline separated input, seems like more generically useful approach. I'm a little confused how --null-input and --raw-input interact, reading the docs on reduce now. I think this needs to be the accepted answer.

Comment: For the second solution, where it is written "for the present case", it works only when values are integers. Just in case someone does like me and paste and cut and try to use it for another case.

Comment: Thanks for the great solution.  I would like to point out that between versions 1.6 and 1.7 of `jq`, splitting behavior seems to have changed with respect to trailing delimiters:  `printf "a\0b\0c\0" | jq -Rs 'split("\u0000")` produces `["a", "b", "c"]` with version 1.6 but with 1.7 it produces `["a", "b", "c", ""]`.  For associative arrays that leads to `{<usual stuff>, "": null}`.  I also tried with 1.5 and it behaves like 1.6.  I composed the string passed to jq differently based on the version using `range(0;lenght/2)` for 1.6 and below, and `range(0;(lenght-1)/2)` for 1.7 and above.

Comment: The solution I went with is `if (( ${jq_minor_version} < 7 )) ; then length_for_jq='(lenght-1)' ; else length_for_jq='(length)' ; fi`.  Where the `jq_minor_version` is from some bash string manipulation to get at the 7 in things like `jq-1.7` or `jq-1.7.1` which is `jq_version=$(jq --version) ; jq_minor_patch=${jq_version##*.} ; jq_minor_version=${jq_minor_patch%%.*}`.  Finally change single quotes for double quotes around the code given to `jq` and replace `length` with `${length_for_jq}`.

Answer (score 5):

You can initialize a variable to an empty object `{}` and add the key/values `{($key):$value}` for each iteration, re-injecting the result in the same variable  :

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A dict=()

dict["foo"]=1
dict["bar"]=2
dict["baz"]=3

data='{}'

for i in "${!dict[@]}"
do
    data=$(jq -n --arg data "$data" \
                 --arg key "$i"     \
                 --arg value "${dict[$i]}" \
                 '$data | fromjson + { ($key) : ($value | tonumber) }')
done

echo "$data"
```

Comment: Nice solution, I like the way data is passed as a jq arg and iteratively extended.

Comment: highly readable.

Comment: Warning that this solution can be slow if dict has a lot of entries

Answer (score 5):

This answer is from `nico103` on `freenode` `#jq`:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A dict=()

dict["foo"]=1
dict["bar"]=2
dict["baz"]=3

assoc2json() {
    declare -n v=$1
    printf '%s\0' "${!v[@]}" "${v[@]}" |
    jq -Rs 'split("\u0000") | . as $v | (length / 2) as $n | reduce range($n) as $idx ({}; .[$v[$idx]]=$v[$idx+$n])'
}

assoc2json dict
```

Comment: Granted, this is using a bunch of bashisms unavoidably, but I'd suggest POSIX-compliant function declaration syntax just to avoid spreading shell-local idioms. `assoc2json() {`, with no `function` keyword, avoids depending on ksh syntax supported by bash only for compatibility purposes.

Comment: Hmm. One thing that worries me here a little, by the way, is that `%q` quotes strings for `eval`-style consumption **by bash**. I'm quite certain that there's a substantial number of inputs for which the processing done here is going to yield something that doesn't evaluate back to the original literal values. On the other hand, it'd be pretty straightforward to adopt the `printf '%s\0'` approach taken in my answer, combining it with the much shorter jq code here (just adopting the string-splitting bits)...

Comment: If you see the answer I (nico103) wrote up below, I meant to leave the dequoting/unescaping to the reader.  It should be easy enough (though maybe not a one-liner).

Comment: Interesting about `printf '%s\0'`!  Thanks for that idea!  jq will turn the NULs into `\u0000`, so you'd have to split on that, which... you can!  So the one-liner is now simpler: `printf '%s\0' "${!arrayvar[@]}" "${arrayvar[@]}" | jq -Rs 'split("\u0000") | . as $v | (length / 2) as $n | reduce range($n) as $idx ({}; .[$v[$idx]]=$v[$idx+$n])'`.

Comment: Changed to POSIX-compliant function declaration syntax as per Charles Duffys suggestion above.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, what do you mean by 'spreading shell-local idioms'?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, why do you think the function keyword is supported only for compatibility purposes? The keyword makes the code more readable and lots of people use it in bash.

Comment: @JánLalinský, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete. The `function` keyword was literally added only because pre-POSIX  ksh had it -- but in ksh, it serves an actual useful purpose, making variables function-local by default. In bash it doesn't even do that, thus making functions defined in this way incompatible between bash and the ksh releases the syntax was taken from. Moreover, the ksh form is `function foo {`, whereas `function foo() {` is a hybrid of the two (POSIX and ksh-compatibility) forms, not itself compatible with *either* POSIX or ksh.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, it seems whoever introduced the keyword function into bash, didn't want to introduce also its original ksh meaning, so perhaps he did not care about 100% compatibility with ksh that much and perhaps there was another reason to introduce it.  Anyways, many years later I think it does not matter what was the original intent, the keyword is there and is useful in some bash scripts: it makes the code more readable.

Comment: @JánLalinský, if someone can only read code that works with bash, and can't read code written for `/bin/sh`, that's rather a significant fault in their skillset, no? Likewise, if we're promulgating habits that cause people to *write* code incompatible with `/bin/sh` without making it clear that that code is bash-only and a different form should be used when cross-shell compatibility is desired, I consider that a clear fault in our teaching.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, that was not what I meant. I meant that using the function keyword improves readability.

Comment: @JánLalinský, ...I also can lean on community consensus here -- the bash-hackers' wiki -- previously linked -- and the [Wooledge BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Functions) are both actively-maintained resources managed by community members who care a great deal about best practices. Similarly, see the [history for the `function` keyword in the freenode #bash channel](http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/function). TLDP's "ABS" promotes the keyword, but it's also woefully undermaintained and unresponsive, even to outright inaccuracies.

Comment: @JánLalinský, it only improves readability to people who've trained their eyes to expect it.

Answer (score 3):

[bash 5.2](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) introduces the `@k` [parameter transformation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) which, makes this much easier. Like:

```
$ declare -A dict=([foo]=1 [bar]=2 [baz]=3)
$ jq -n '[$ARGS.positional | _nwise(2) | {(.[0]): .[1]}] | add' --args "${dict[@]@k}"
{
  "foo": "1",
  "bar": "2",
  "baz": "3"
}
```

Comment: Nice, might need to make this the accepted answer in a few years when this version is more common.

Comment: This version gave me an error:
> ./echo-args.sh: line 23: ${args[@]@k}: bad substitution
Where as the accepted answer "Generic solution" did not and output my args correctly
> {
  "9": "-s",
  "8": "alpha1",
  "7": "-e",
  "6": "foo",
  "5": "-b",
  "4": "foo-foo-foo-foo-01",
  "3": "-r",
  "2": "foo-foo-foo-foo-01",
  "1": "-n",
  "20": "fooFoo",
  "18": "foo",
  "19": "-f",
  "12": 9092,
  "13": "-c",
  "10": "foo-alpha1",
  "11": "-p",
  "16": "alpha2.dev2.foo.io",
  "17": "-l",
  "14": "",
  "15": "-h"
}

Comment: @Darrell it says *bash-5.2*, you have an older version.

Comment: @oguzismail ah yes apologies, ~downvote removed.~ stack over flow won't let me remove my downvote :-(

Comment: @Darrell it's ok. you can remove it now if you want. have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

This has been posted, and credited to nico103 on IRC, which is to say, me.

The thing that scares me, naturally, is that these associative array keys and values need quoting.  Here's a start that requires some additional work to dequote keys and values:

```
function assoc2json {
    typeset -n v=$1
    printf '%q\n' "${!v[@]}" "${v[@]}" |
        jq -Rcn '[inputs] |
                . as $v |
                (length / 2) as $n |
                reduce range($n) as $idx ({}; .[$v[$idx]]=$v[$idx+$n])'
}


$ assoc2json a
{"foo\\ bar":"1","b":"bar\\ baz\\\"\\{\\}\\[\\]","c":"$'a\\nb'","d":"1"}
$
```

So now all that's needed is a jq function that removes the quotes, which come in several flavors:

- if the string starts with a single-quote (ksh) then it ends with a single quote and those need to be removed
- if the string starts with a dollar sign and a single-quote and ends in a double-quote, then those need to be removed and internal backslash escapes need to be unescaped
- else leave as-is

I leave this last iterm as an exercise for the reader.

I should note that I'm using `printf` here as the iterator!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ declare -A d=([$'foo\naha']=$'a\nb' [bar]=2 [baz]=$'{"x":0}')
$ a2j='$ARGS.positional | [.[:$n], .[$n:]] | transpose | map({ (first): last }) | add'
$ jq -nc "$a2j" --argjson n ${#d[@]} --args "${!d[@]}" "${d[@]}"
{"bar":"2","baz":"{\"x\":0}","foo\naha":"a\nb"}
```

This combine arbitrary bash keys by [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44792751/8344420), use of jq arg by
[bertrand martel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44792595/8344420), but use `${#d[@]}`, `${!d[@]}` and `${d[@]}` to get
number of elements, keys and values in the array instead instead of
`${d[@]@k}` by [oguz ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73862706/8344420).
This allow a simple jq expression without `_nwise`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.