# sh: How to write an array to a json file using jq

Tags: sh, jq

How can I write the array to a json file?

```
#!/bin/sh
declare -A myarray 
myarray["testkey"]="testvalue"
myarray["testkey1"]="testvalue1"
myarray["testkey2"]="testvalue2"

jq -n --arg $myarray[@] > file.json
```

EDIT:

The json file should contain the following:

```
{
  "testkey": "testvalue",
  "testkey1": "testvalue1", 
  "testkey2": "testvalue2"
}
```

Comment: I wrote an answer and only then stumbled on this, which is a pretty close duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792241/constructing-a-json-hash-from-a-bash-associative-array It has a little bit extra around parsing integers but otherwise it's the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructing a json hash from a bash associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792241/constructing-a-json-hash-from-a-bash-associative-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way that doesn't need an extra step before to serialise the associative array:

```
jq -n '
    $ARGS.positional|
    . as $a|
    (length/2) as $l|
    [range($l)|{key:$a[.],value:$a[.+$l]}]|
    from_entries' --args "${!myarray[@]}" "${myarray[@]}"
```

It should work even with newlines in the keys or values. The one caveat is that *technically* bash doesn't guarantee that `${!myarray[@]}` will output the keys [in the same order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54306133/do-keys-a-and-values-a-of-associative-arrays-expand-in-the-same-ord) that `${myarray[@]}` will output the values. It *does* do that in practice, and it's hard to imagine an implementation that *wouldn't,* but if you *really* want to be safe here's a variation on [Inian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64595305/2283) that should be safe to newlines. It also  assembles a single object.

```
for key in "${!myarray[@]}"; do 
    printf "%s\0%s\0" "$key" "${myarray[$key]}"
done | 
jq -sR '
    split("\u0000")|
    . as $elements|
    [range(length/2)|{key:$elements[2*.],value:$elements[2*.+1]}]|
    from_entries'
```

Comment: Nice! but do add a note `$ARGS.positional` is a jq-1.6 thingy

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative to `jq`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
declare -A myarray
myarray["testkey"]="testvalue"
myarray["testkey1"]="testvalue1"
myarray["testkey2"]="testvalue2"

cols=$(printf "%s," "${!myarray[@]}")
column -J --table-name 'myTable' --table-columns "${cols}"  <<<"${myarray[@]}"
```